# Using html2pdf to generate a report using php and mvc pattern

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdf-generation, fpdf

I have setup an application that somehow uses a front-controller. And I came across a library called **html2pdf**. This library converts html to pdf.

Like this:

```
<?php
    $content = "
     <page>
      <h1>Exemple d'utilisation</h1>
      <br>
      Ceci est un <b>exemple d'utilisation</b>
      de <a href='http://html2pdf.fr/'>HTML2PDF</a>.<br>
     </page>";

   require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
   $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
   $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
   $html2pdf->Output('exemple.pdf');
?>
```

As you can see, the libary can transform that html to a pdf. It can even read an html file and convert it to pdf.

Okay here is the setup of my controller.

```
class TestController extends Controller {
    private $template;

    public function __construct(View $view = null) {
        parent::__construct($view);
        $this->template = 'test'; // replace this
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->view->data['someinfo'] = 'information about me';
        $this->view->render($this->template);
    }
}
```

My idea is, instead of rendering the template out, and replacing `$someinfo` variable by `information about me` because I used the `extract` function of php.

I could just replace the variables, and then save the output as html, so that I could use html2pdf to convert it to pdf?

Are there already implementation of this? Or are there more efficient solutions rather than creating and html file and converting it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the ZendFramework MVC you might do something like this in the controller:

```
function toPdfAction()  { 
   // I need a different layout 
   $this->getHelper('layout')->setLayout('pdf-layout'); 
   $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout(); 

   // we need to do renderering ourselves.   
   $this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender(); 

   /* @var $layout Zend_Layout */ 
   $layout = $this->_helper->layout->getLayoutInstance(); 
   $layout->assign('content', $this->view->render('mycontroller/myaction.tpl')); 

   $output = $layout->render(); 

   // now we still need to ensure that the rendering is not sent to the browser 
   $this->getResponse()->clearBody(); 

   // now do something with $ouput like convert it to PDF and stream it back
}
```

However, the answer is going to MVC implementation specific. If you are not using Zend, that likely won't work for you. What MVC Framework are you using?

Comment: I created a mini-mvc framework, yeah I think prolly that won't be applicable to my framework, but I can take a look on how zend does it.

Comment: Well .. putting something like this in a controller would be against the basic principles of MVC and MVC-inspired design patterns. Just because Zend does it this way, does not mean that it is a good practice.

Comment: @tereško, yeah, it'll surely break the 'good practice'. I wonder how can I do it.